# Sorting the strings in an NSMutableArray in Iphone Sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I have objects in my NSMUtableArray and I need to sort them in descending order based on the tax.taxName.Can any body suggest me how to do this.

Hope I get Quick response from you guys.

Thanks in advance.
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If assume right, that the objects in your array are of a custom class, implement a method in that class:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByTax:(id)other
{
  return [[self valueForKeyPath: @"tax.taxName"] compare: [other valueForKeyPath: @"tax.taxName"]];
}
```

Then do the following:

```
[array sortUsingSelector: @selector(compareByTax:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS4 you can use comparators with this NSArray message:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

you would write something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id object1, id object2) { // return NSComparisonResult ... }]
```

Another possibility is to define a c function which is used as callback with this NSArray message:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context
```

Take a look in the NSArray Documentation there are messages for sorting with selectors or descriptors also. It depends on what fits best for you.